# Dataset with biggest events in the world/region, reporting number of attendees, geolocation and date

Tags: data-request, geospatial

I want to build a dynamic representation of the most popular events in a region over a certain period of time. I was thinking Europe, but if there is no dataset available I could do it for the US.
Regarding the time I would like to have at least 2-3 years, even though 10 would be better.

What I need is the date, event name, geolocation and number of attendees (or estimate number of attendees). It would be even better if events are already categorised by type (sport, protest, etc..).

Answer (score 4):

Here's a slightly off-topic, but perhaps interesting pick from Wikipedia on the (estimated) [Largest peaceful gatherings in history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_largest_peaceful_gatherings_in_history), mainly for religious occasions. Some examples:

> An estimated 20 to 25 million people visited the shrine of Husayn ibn Ali in Karbala, Iraq during Arba'een in December 2013.
>
> An estimated 4.2 million people attended a concert given by Rod Stewart in Rio de Janeiro, Brazil on 1996-12-31.
>
> An estimated 1.25 million people attended a Papal mass given by Pope John Paul II in the Phoenix Park, Dublin, Ireland on 29 September 1979.

Similar lists by topic could get you started on [multi-sport evens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_multi-sport_events) (like the Olympic Games), [running events](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_largest_running_events), the [largest concerts ever](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Largest_concerts_ever)...

Comment: That's a pretty cool list; will need some additional work of course.

Comment: Yupp; geocoding time-dependent stuff (aka "events") still seems to be in its infancy...

Answer (score 3):

Eventbrite is a platform where everyone can create an event and most of the BIG events use it as well. Also, eventbrite has an API for developers. I haven't used it, but maybe you could ask for an API key and use it to find all previous events with details such as attendees and dates.

The developers' site is [this one](http://developer.eventbrite.com/).

Comment: Cool API resource.